# What matlab release do I need to be able to use `webread`?

Tags: matlab, web-services, rest

I have matlab R2010a installed on my computer. I tried to use `webread`to read content from RESTful web service. I can't found it in matlab R2010a. What matlab release do I need to be able to use `webread`?

Comment: `webread` was released in version 2014b - you need to upgrade to this version or above to use this function.

Comment: In the future, [look at the bottom left](http://i.imgur.com/DDuZQxE.png) of the help page to see when a feature was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

From the help page of [webread](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop):

> Introduced in R2014b

Therefore, R2014b and newer releases of Matlab should work.